# Proving that ${(1-\frac{2}{x^2})}^x < \frac{x-1}{x+1}$ for any $x > 2$.

Tags: limits, inequality, binomial-coefficients

Proof that ${\left(1-\dfrac{2}{x^2}\right)}^x\!< \dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$ for any $x > 2$.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}-x\ln(1-2/x^2)$. It suffices to show that $f(x)>0$ for $x>2$, as $\ln$ is an increasing function. Using the series for $\ln(1+a)=a-a^2/3+a^3/3-a^4/4+\dots$, we get the asymptotic expansion
$$
\ln \frac{x-1}{x+1}=\ln \left(1-\frac1x\right)-\ln \left(1+\frac1x\right)=-\frac{2}{x}-\frac{2}{3x^3}-\frac{2}{5x^5}-\frac{2}{7x^7}-\dots
$$
and
$$
-x\ln\left(1-\frac2{x^2}\right)=\frac2x+\frac{2^2}2 \frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{2^3}3 \frac{1}{x^5}+\frac{2^4}4 \frac{1}{x^7}+\dots
$$
hence
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{x^{2k+1}}\left(\frac{2^{k + 1}}{k + 1} - \frac2{2k+1}\right)>0
$$
since
$$
\frac{2^{k + 1}}{k + 1} - \frac2{2k+1}=2\frac{2^k(2k+1)-(k+1)}{(k+1)(2k+1)}>0.
$$
(Note that the inequality $f(x)>0$ holds for all $x>\sqrt 2$.)

Answer (score 4):

Hi @max We can use Binomial series as we have :

$$\left(1-\frac{2}{x^{2}}\right)\leq \left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x+1}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{x}-1}$$

So at order two we have :

$$\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x+1}\right)^{-1}\left(1+\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x+1}-1\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x+1}-1\right)^{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\leq \left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

But :

$$\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x+1}\right)^{-1}\left(1+\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x+1}-1\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{x+1}-1\right)^{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\left(1-\frac{2}{x^{2}}\right)$$

We are done !

---

---

Some idea fo someone who wants to show Angelo problem :

For $x\geq 2$ we have :

$$\cos\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\geq 2\left|\frac{x-1}{x^{2}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}x}\right|\geq \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$$

Remains to show :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos\left(\frac{2}{x^{2n}}\right)-\left(\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^{2n}+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{2n}}}$$

Comment: @Angelo It follows from Gerber's theorem (your deleted comment) for $x>-1$ and $n\in N,\alpha\in R$: $$\dbinom{\alpha}{n+1}x^{n+1}\geq 0\implies (1+x)^{\alpha}\geq \sum_{i=0}^{n}\dbinom{\alpha}{i}x^i$$

Comment: @Angelo I haven't the time now but I shall think to that :-).

Comment: Erik, you are right, for that reason I deleted my previous comment. Since $\alpha\in(1,2)$ and $y\in(-1,0)\,,\,$ it results that $\displaystyle{\alpha\choose3}y^3>0$. But if $\alpha$ were greater than $2$, it would be false.

Comment: Erik, could you prove that $\;\left(\cos\dfrac2x\right)^x<\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}\;$ for any $\;x>\dfrac4\pi\;?$

Comment: @Angelo I give you some hint .

Comment: Erik, how have you proved those inequalities ?

Comment: @Angelo use the bound $$\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\ge \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{1/x}$$ log and derivative.

Comment: Erik, I did what you said but I cannot get the inequalities $\cos\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\geq 2\left|\frac{x-1}{x^{2}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}x}\right|\geq \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$ Please, could you write the complete proof of these inequalities in your answer ?

Comment: @Angelo See the linked question of mine I show it for $x\geq 4$

Answer (score 3):

Taking logarithms leads to

$$
x\log\left(1-\frac2{x^2}\right)\lt\log(x-1)-\log(x+1)
$$

and thus

$$
\log\left(1-\frac2{x^2}\right)\lt\frac1x\left(\log\left(1-\frac1x\right)-\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\right)\;.
$$

So we want to show that

$$
\log\left(1-2z^2\right)\lt z(\log(1-z)-\log(1+z))
$$

for $0\lt z\lt\frac12$. Expanding both sides into power series leads to

$$
-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left(2z^2\right)^k}k\lt-z\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{z^j}j-\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-z)^j}j\right)
$$

and thus

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^k}kz^{2k}\gt\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac2{2k-1}z^{2k}\;.
$$

The claim follows since the terms for $k=1$ are equal and all other terms are larger on the left. This in fact holds for $0\lt z\lt\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and thus for $x\gt\sqrt2$.

Comment: I don't see you often here and I like your solution !

Comment: @ErikSatie: Thanks! Yes, I'm here on and off; I used to do a lot here in the past, and now during the last month, but not in the years in between.

Comment: @joriki, I am very interested in the following inequality: $$\left(\cos\dfrac2x\right)^x<\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}\quad\text{for any }\;x>\dfrac4\pi\;.$$Could you help me prove it ?

Comment: @Angelo: What a coincidence that you just happened to come across this related question that was asked only $6$ hours ago! That's going to be slightly more difficult because of the extra powers in the expansion of the cosine. It wouldn't be appropriate to do it in the comments, but if you post that as a new question, notify me here and I'll give it a try.

Comment: @joriki, it is not any coincidence, indeed $\;1-\dfrac2{x^2}\;$ are the first two terms of the expansion of $\;\cos\dfrac2x\;.$

Comment: @Angelo: Yes, I'm aware of that – I meant the coincidence that you came across this related question by someone else only a couple of hours after they asked it – that was quite unlikely, wasn't it? :-)

Comment: @joriki, no, it is not. I tried to prove the OP’s inequality even though I could not, but during my attempts I figured out that the inequality with the function cosine held too.

Comment: @Angelo: Ah, I see.